# Why do we start subroutine with HEX 0?

Tags: assembly

In assembly languages, when we start subroutine by using BSA, it starts with 
 , HEX 0
What does it mean?
many books say 'store the return address', but return address should be stored before subroutine, I think.

Comment: Which assembly are you referring?

Comment: Some ancient computers did have callers store a return address before the start of a function because they didn't have a stack or link-register.  What architecture is this for?  Also, show a specific example of what you're talking about.  Copy/paste some code into a code-formatting block.